# Google Plus One button backend error -32099

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus, google-plus-one

I've added google plus one buttons on [site](http://qbash.ru).

Everything has been working fine for 3-4 months.

But now when i click a button it turns into an exclamation mark and i get the next json from google:

```
[
    {
        "error": 
        {
            "code": -32099,
            "message": "Backend Error",
            "data": 
            [
                {
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "backendError",
                    "message": "Backend Error"
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "pos.plusones.insert"
    }
]
```

Does anybody know the reason of such error?

P.S. I've also read [this article](https://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=plusone_button_error&answer=1199142). But i have working google plus one buttons on [another site](http://www.linux-faq.org/) that is on the same hosting as the first.

Comment: It sounds like google is to blame. Not you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that the data-href you are passing to the +1 button returned an HTTP 500 error when Google tried to fetch the page.

For example, I tried the +1 button which references http://qbash.ru/Quotations/Details/339, but fetching that URL returns:

Извините, во время обработки Вашего запроса произошла ошибка.

With the headers:

```
Request URL:http://qbash.ru/Quotations/Details/339
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score -2):

Also this is the UA of GP+ fetcher:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0
```

Make sure it's not banned.

Answer (score -2):

Check if you are running ZBBlock - the latest signatures (as of 26th Jan) seem to automatically ban this user agent as being "a severely outdated version of Firefox which matches a trojan profile"

I have reported this on the ZBBlock forums

Answer (score -2):

I think this happens when Google can't reach your page. For example i am working on my local environment which is unreachable and i get the same error/response.